# Data model for unique sets

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling

I am hunting for the best way to implement a data model for "recipes"

think like a pizza app where you can compose your own pizza. you select maybe 5 out of 100 ingredients and you select an amount for each. I need to check if I've "seen" that pizza combination before, assign ID if I have not, and retrieve ID if I have.

We have *n* ingredients.

A recipe is defined by a set of ingredients and a corresponding amount.

Could look like:

Ingr1 90
Ingr2 10

or
Ingr1 90
Ingr2 10
Ingr3 10

I want to store this in a structure where I give each unique recipe an ID, and so it's possible for me to query for the ID given the recipe data set.

I want a stored procedure that takes a data set as a parameter and returns an ID that is new if the recipe was unknown and existing if the recipe already exists.

I am looking for the most efficient way of doing this. My best idea so far is to either encode the recipe as a string (json) and use this as a unique constraint, or have a stored procedure that iterates through the recipe data set and constructs a n level deep if exists statement.

So, I'm confident I can solve the problem, but am looking for a beautiful method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have entities Recipe and Ingredient and M:M relation between them. Data model can look like this (PK in bold):

Recipe (**RecipeID**, RecipeName)

Ingredient(**IngredientID**, IngredientName)

RecipeIngredients(**RecipeID**, **IngredientID**, Amount)

You can solve task of finding out if same recipe is already present in a database using query but this query wouldn't be simple. It is well-know problem, relational division. There are several approaches. One of the most popular is counting. If some recipe has same amount of ingredients as target one and all ingredients are the same, then they are equal. Such queries often involves data aggregations and perform not very fast on big amount of data.

You can help to solve this problem from application side and you are thinking in right direction. Represent recipe as a string, ordering values by IngredientID (to get same string even if ingredients were added in different order), converting Amount in some stable form (not to get 0.499999 instead of 0.5), calculate some hash out of string, and store this value in Recipe. In simple form hash is an integer value, so you can find doubles very fast.

So it is your call. Every approach has it's own issues. Heavy query in first case and hassle to keep hash in actual state in second case (and possible collisions too). I'd stick with first option until it works OK and start any optimizations only when they are unavoidable.

Query example (new recipe is in #tmp):

```
;with totals as
(
  select RecipeID, count(*) totals
  from RecipeIngredients
  group by RecipeID
), matched_totals as
(
  select i.RecipeID, count(*) matched_totals
  from RecipeIngredients i
    join #tmp t
      on i.IngredientID = t.IngredientID
        and i.Amount = t.Amount
  group by i.RecipeID
)
select t.*
from totals t
  join matched_totals m
    on m.RecipeID = t.RecipeID
where
  totals = matched_totals
  and totals = (select count(*) from #tmp)
```

This solution is more elegant but much less intuitive:

```
select * 
from Recipe r
where
  not exists 
    ( select 1 
      from RecipeIngredients ri
      where 
        r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID
        and not exists
        (select 1 from #tmp t where t.IngredientID = ri.IngredientID)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks - I am glad to see that I am not overlooking a super simple and elegant solution :)